# how do you compare 2 values containing a dash?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following piece of xslt code.

```
<xsl:if test="not(boolean(s0:FICHE_PRODUCT_ID = following::s0:POLLINGSTMTRECORD/s0:FICHE_PRODUCT_ID)) or position()=last()">
```

this worked fine until i had the following two SKUs to compare.

> WKL203-001
>
> WKL203-CRIMSON

Since a dash is some kind of escape, he is comparing only the WKL203 part. if i edit the xml and use `&#8211;` it works for the above but the xml is created by the database so it isn't an option to send that code. Is there a way in XSLT too either change the - to this code or a way to make the if ignore the dash?

Comment: Could you not put some code between when you retrieve it from the database and when you parse it through xslt to search for and replace all instances of the dash?

Comment: @JonoRR I never mentioned it, but this is done in biztalk, so actually yes, i can call a C# code block and change it. that should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually replace the dash character before it reaches the XSLT and becomes an escape character.

Long as you have access to code after database retrieval, just use a find and replace on the database results before passing it to XSLT.